# turn off auto-fill in org tables?

Tags: org-mode, auto-fill-mode

I have `(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)` in my config file, and I'm noticing that in org mode, auto-fill/wrapping occurs even within (wide) tables, which I don't like.

I confirmed that if I set the variable to `nil`, this no longer happens, but I don't want to disable this across the whole file, just in the tables. Is there some way to say "I want auto-fill, but not inside my org tables"?

Answer (score 1):

Try *not* setting `auto-fill-function` at all in your config file: it is set from `normal-auto-fill-function` which is `do-auto-fill` by default, but it is `org-auto-fill` in Org mode buffers. There is no need for you to set it.

That way, with an Org mode buffer, and with `auto-fill` mode turned on, normal paragraphs get filled appropriately but table entries are not touched. You can check the value of `normal-auto-fill-function` in that buffer by using `C-h v normal-auto-fill-function`, which should say:

> normal-auto-fill-function is a variable defined in ‘simple.el’.
>
> Its value is ‘org-auto-fill-function’
> Local in buffer foo.org; global value is do-auto-fill

Comment: Did you try this? Did it work? If you delete the customization completely, does that resolve your problem?